# Raphael -- object rotation at arbitrary position

Tags: object, rotation, position, raphael

I'm using Raphael_2.01 and would like to rotate an object at arbitrary position.

(WindowsXP, Firefox3.6)

example: http://uproda11.2ch-library.com/326446b6u/11326446.png

This rectangle (rect0) rotates thirty degrees at its lower right point.

The parameters are:

```
var rectX = rect0.getBBox().x;
var rectY = rect0.getBBox().y;
var rectW = rect0.getBBox().width;
var rectH = rect0.getBBox().height;

var rot = 30;// rotation
var rotX, rotY;// arbitrary position
```

What code should I use ?   I can't image suitable method.

thanks,

Comment: You need to learn the math, or use something like Rapael.Freetransform

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it's `rect0.rotate(30, rotX, rotY);`.

Comment: Thank you Elbert, I've succeeded. It's "super" simple!